# Blazor wasm Asp.Net Core Hosted Deployed to local IIS 404

Tags: blazor-client-side

I deployed a Blazor .Net hosted project to localhost, first Modified the base tag:

```
<base href="/MyBlazor/" />
```

and after Publish I created rewrite rules to map Non File, Non root paths to /MyBlazor, The web site is working, But when I want to navigate, only NavLinks work but "a" tags and uriHelper.Navigate("...") are not working and return 404, How to make them work?